# Discord.js - Check list bot

Tags: node.js, bots, discord.js

I'm currently developing a discord bot using `discord.js` for a private usage.

**Here's a little context:** in my server we organize events with 30 - 40 members in a voice channel (all of them have roles corresponding to events), and we need to check who's missing. So basically the bot need to compare 2 list, members with event role who's are connected on the voice channel and another one with those whose have the role but are not connected on the designated voice channel.

I've done some research, I have the bases of how it should work (retrieving the voice channel id where the admin is, and getting the role from the command). However, it's more complicated than I've thought and I require assistance.

Here's my "code":

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if(message.content == "check"){
        //role restriction
        if(!!message.member.roles.cache.has("admin")) return console.log("Fail from "+message.author.username);
        else{
            //retreiving the role from command
            var messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
            var command = messageArray[0];
            var args = messageArray.slice(1)
            //finding the correct channel with the gaved ID
            console.log(message.guild.channels.cache
                .find(VoiceChannel => VoiceChannel.id == 618882800950706189))


            //voice channel ID where admin is connected
            //console.log(message.member.voice.channelID);

        };
    };
});
```

I will appreciate every help I'll get :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things you are doing wrong, the `RoleManager` you get from `.cache` returns a `Collection` [See here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=has)

A collection is basically an array of array tuples that look like `[key, value]`, the key is usually a ID (string, which you used as a number in your code example) and the value represents the actual value, in this case a role, from what I understand you are having troubles getting the connected members with the role and the members who have the role who are not connected, I have adjusted your code, I hope it gives you a general idea

```js
client.on("message", message => {
  // This prevents the bot from responding to bots
  if (message.autor.bot) {
    return;
  }

  // ES6 array destructuring + rest spread operator allows us to easily
  // get the first word from an array and keep the rest as an array
  const [command, ...args] = message.content.split(/ +/);

  if (command === "check") {
    // Check if the member has the admin role using Collection#some
    if (!message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "admin")) {
      return console.log(`Fail from ${message.author.username}`);
    }

    // Attempt to get the channel from the collection using the ID from user input
    // Note that this could be undefined!
    const voiceChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(args[0]);

    // Collection of members who have the event role
    const eventMembers = message.guild.members.cache.filter(m =>
      m.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "event")
    );

    // Collection of members with the event role who are connected
    // Using Collection#filter and Collection#has
    const connectedMembers = eventMembers.members.filter(m =>
      voiceChannel.members.has(m.id)
    );

    // Collection of members with the event role but are not connected
    const disconnectedMembers = eventMembers.members.filter(
      m => !voiceChannel.members.has(m.id)
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the adjustment. But it seems to contain some errors, when I'm connected to a voice channel the voiceChannel result as an undefined, and ever after fixing it the last part give me nothing. I thought a .cache is require after a collection (like in the link you've provided) but nothing change.
The eventMembers give me this error (`message.guild.members.filter` is not a function), then impossible to check the two last collection because they depend on it.

Comment: Try `message.guild.members.cache` instead

Comment: Another error, but with `message.guild.members.cache.filter` instead it work but gave another error at `m.role.some` (is not a function), and if I put a .cache between role and some the result seems to be null :
`Map(2) {_array: null, _keyArray: null}
no debug adapter`.

Comment: I don’t think the cache is necessary there, but it’s roles instead of role

Comment: Mistake in my comment but not in the code, sorry. Without a .cache the debugger tell me `m.roles.some` is not a function.

Comment: I have edited the code, according to the docs it should work like this, if you get empty results try to console log instead, otherwise double check the actual role name

Comment: I've double check roles names and everything's good, but here's what I [get](https://imgur.com/HATa5ty)
row 61 is console.log(eventMembers)
row 65 is `const connectedMembers = eventMembers.members.filter(m =>
      voiceChannel.members.has(m.id)
      );`

Comment: Are you sure you are running this in a server and not in a DM channel? You might want to create a new question for this, it's saying that message.guild.members or message.guild.members.cache is undefined which should not be the case when you are in a server, it is out of the scope of this question