# Discord.j - Function strangely empty

Tags: node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

this question is linked to another one. If you need to know why I'm asking this, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60789578/discord-js-check-list-bot).

I'm developing a bot who should get a collection filled with members who have a specific role. But after testing and double checking role name and be sure I'm testing the bot in a server and not in DM the collection is always empty and unusable (the program couldn't run without it).

```
const eventMembers = message.guild.members.cache.filter(m =>
      m.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "event")
   );

const connectedMembers = eventMembers.members.filter(m => {
      return voiceChannel.members.has(m.id)
   });
console.log(connectedMembers);
```

If anybody has a hint or a solution I take it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot return :)

```js
const eventMembers = message.guild.members.cache.filter(m => {
    return  m.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "event")
      });
```

or

```js
const eventMembers = message.guild.members.cache.filter(m => m.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "event"));
```

You can check for the role with this name exist:

```js
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'event')
if (role) {
    console.log('ok')
} else {
    console.log('No role found with this nickname')
}
```

**V2**

```js
const eventMembers = message.guild.members.cache.filter(m => {
    return  m.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "event") && m.voice && m.voice.channelID === message.member.voice.channelID
   });
```

or

```js
const eventMembers = message.guild.members.cache.filter(m => m.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "event") && m.voice && m.voice.channelID === message.member.voice.channelID)
```

**V3** :D

```js
bot.on('message', message => {
    if(message.content === '!test') {
        if(!message.member.voice.channel) return message.reply('You need joinVoiceChannel for use this command');
        let targetRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'event')
        if (!targetRole) return message.reply('Can`t find a role');
        let eventMembersNotInVoice = targetRole.members.filter(member => member.voice.channelID !== message.member.voice.channelID)
        console.log(eventMembersNotInVoice.size)
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but `console.log(eventMembers)` still giving me an empty array, then others filter couldn't be used. I'll edit the question and adding the last part, maybe it could help.

Comment: @codingNoob what is the `voiceChannel.member`?

Comment: It's members with the event role connected in the same voiceChannel as me

Comment: i add V2 version, better check same voice like this.

Comment: I think I have something. I might be wrong, but I think the problem is not where I'd thought, when I `console.log(eventMembers)` it results whit `Map(2) {_array: null, _keyArray: null}`. But 2 is how many members with the event role are on the server, however `connectMembers` results with `TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`. 
I ignore if `eventMembers` is empty, I'm not comfortable with collections but maybe the `connectedMembers` constant is the problem (or how it should be determinate by the program).

Comment: So, you need send message, and get members with some role and if they in same channel with you. Right?

Comment: The goal is to know who's missing, but yes all members are in the same channel as me

Comment: @codingNoob i\`m add v3 version with standart event message block. Its return a members with role event and who not joined to yo same voice channel as message author. You can replace `!==` to `===` in `member.voice.channelID !== message.member.voice.channelID` for get members who not missing.

Comment: Wow, I have no word, it's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks :)
 Just need to change the `console.log` to get usernames in Discord and I'll deploy it.